# Lego Mindstorms - Server Client messaging between PC and Ev3

Tags: python, messaging, micropython, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

**Disclaimer, this question has already been asked by Liam K. However the answer does not resolve the issue.**

We followed the official Lego Mindstorms tutorial https://pybricks.com/ev3-micropython/messaging.html#server-and-client on messaging between two ev3's. In the comments of the code provided by the tutorial it mentioned being able to connect to a PC as well. However if we run the server code on the PC it terminates immediately, after saying that it is connected, however it did not wait for a response from a client. We would expect the server to not terminate due to the `mbox.wait()` command but it does terminate.

This question is the exact same question that Liam K. asked [Send Data between EV3 and PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940105/send-data-between-ev3-and-pc). However the solution using an API would not work for us since we need a real time connection between the PC and the ev3. This is because we need to constantly send movement data to our ev3 robot. We do not want to use the internet for that and an API would not be practical since the PC should send commands to the ev3 and not vice versa, where the ev3 asks for commands from the PC.

Preferably we want to use the code provided by the tutorial as we want to continue using python/micropython.

Has anyone encounter this issue before and know how to resolve it?

I am new, if this question is missing important information, please let me know.